# Probability Mass function and Variance Question

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

Given the following probability mass function, can you obtain k such that Var(X)=1.5?

X=0 , P(0)= 3k

X=1 , P(1)= 2k

X=2 , P(2)= k

I know that Var(X)=E(X^2)-(E(X))^2 and that E(X)= ΣXP(X). I did the respective calculations for both E(X^2) resulting in 6k and E(X) resulting in 4k. Now the following is what confuses me...

Var(X)= 6k - (4k)^2

Var(X)= 6k - 16k^2

1.5 = 6k - 16k^2 ????

the following results in a negative root which cant be right. Is there something I missed here? I dont think I made any errors in calculation, is there another step or concept I need to apply?

Thanks for the help

Comment: If $0,1,2$ are the only possible values of $X$, we have no freedom about  $k$, it is $\frac{1}{6}$ since probabilities add to $1$. Can you check the problem statement?

Comment: The exercise is odd: if X takes only the values 0, 1 and 2, then k+2k+3k=1 hence k=1/6. Thus, k is not a free parameter. Or X can also take integer values greater than 2? Please check what was asked from you.

Comment: OH, I think that maybe that is the answer...usually questions tell you to obtain the value but here it asks using 'can'. I think I was suppose to invoke the concept of the sum of P(X)=1. Thanks